# Why there is Unhandled Exception in this code?

Tags: java, exception

I came accross the following code:

```
class Animal{
    public void eat() throws Exception {}
}

class Dog extends Animal{
    public void eat(){} //no exception thrown
    public static void main(String[] args){
          Animal a = new Dog();
          Dog d = new Dog();
          d.eat();   //ok
          a.eat();  //does not compile!..(1)
    }
}
```

Here, (1) does not compile even though at runtime Dog's eat() method will be called. Why does this happen? What is the reason that Java supports this? Shouldn't this be filed as a bug?

Comment: exception throws part is not part of method signature...

Comment: Because the class `Animal` doesn't have an `eat` method! Java doesn't automatically cast. You have to do it yourself.

Comment: @MichaelGoldstein that is not true. It contains in this case.

Comment: In this very simplistic example, it may be easy enough to determine that `a` is a `Dog`, but in most real-world cases, it would not be so simple. `a` is of type `Animal`, so the compiler treats it as an `Animal`.

Comment: Animal defines eat as throwing an exception, as far as the compiler is concerned, you've failed to handle the exception (the compiler only knows that a is of type animal)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're using an `Animal` reference to refer to a `Dog`. And the signature of `Animal.eat` includes the `Exception`. The compiler knows that a `Dog` is a kind of `Animal`, but once you use an `Animal` reference it doesn't know that it's a `Dog` until runtime.

To put it another way, all `Dog`(s) are `Animal`(s) but not all `Animal`(s) are `Dog`(s).

**Edit**

You could have added a cast

```
((Dog) a).eat();  //would compile
```

At runtime, that will fail if `a` isn't in fact a `Dog`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Animal a = new Dog();
```

in `OOP (Object Oriented Programming)`, this is called `polymorphism`. And in Java (and mostly in OOP support language such as C#), this behavior is compile checking. That means compiler at **compile time** just knows a is a animal, and cannot know a is a dog until **runtime.**

For example:

```
Animal a = new Dog();
a.bark(); // cannot. because compiler doesn't know a is a dog until runtime
((Dog)a).bark(); // yes. we say to compiler: a **must** be a dog
```

Another example is:

```
    Animal a = new Cat();
    // yes. can compile. we force compiler to know this animal is a dog. 
    //but will run-time exception because in fact this is a cat
    ((Dog)a).bark();
```

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 3):

First thing that you are not following the rules of **Method Overriding**. if Base class method is throwing any Exception then child class method must throw equal or Low Level Exception. now this code will work fine because its following the method overriding rules. Also @Elliot is saying right thing, compiler doesn't aware of dog object(as Animal is referring) at compile time. it will resolve only at Run Time.

```
class Animal{
public void eat() throws Exception {}
}

class Test extends Animal{
  public void eat()throws Exception{} 
  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
      Animal a = new Test();
      Test d = new Test();
      d.eat();
      a.eat();  
}
}
```